# Bootstrap flex-wrap div not pushing second div to the side to accommodate flex-item(s)

Tags: css, html, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have two divs, sharing a parent (flex-row) div.
The first of these divs is a column, in which there's several small elements. The second is a simple long vertical block.

The expected behaviour (though this might be where I'm wrong) is that when the column of items doesn't have enough height and wraps its elements in a second column, the div would expand to be wider to display these wrapped elements and push the second div (the long vertical block) to the side.

What actually happens is that the first div wraps correctly, but instead of pushing the other div further right, it displays wrapped items *underneath* the 
second div, so under the long block.

html:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row block-div">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-wrap small-block-div">
    <div class="small-block flex-item"></div>
    <div class="small-block flex-item"></div>
    <div class="small-block flex-item"></div>
    <div class="small-block flex-item"></div>
    <div class="small-block flex-item"></div>
    <div class="small-block flex-item"></div>
    <div class="small-block flex-item"></div>
    <div class="small-block flex-item"></div>
    <div class="small-block flex-item"></div>
    <div class="small-block flex-item"></div>
    <div class="small-block flex-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="big-block flex-item">
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.block-div {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%
}

.small-block-div {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.small-block  {
  width: 6em;
  height: 4em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.big-block {
  width: 4em;
  height: 25em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

How can I make the `small-block-div` become wider as the child elements wrap?

I've attempted using `100vh` instead of `100%` with no changes, tried `display:inline` and `display:block` (and `d-inline-flex` as class), tried just removing the `block-div` and `small-block-div` classes in case they were overwriting default bootstrap behaviour somehow, which doesn't *seem* to be the case.

Tried `flex-container` and just `wrap` instead of `flex-wrap` as classes (on the `small-block-div`), also to no avail.

Apologies if this has been asked before, I went through all the suggested related questions but did not find anything that seemed to immediately be the same issue as I'm having.

Edit: figured I'd add a codepen link! 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NyxGow
Code might not be 1:1 accurate to the above code because I've still been messing with it trying to fix it but the behaviour is the same.

Comment: That does seem to be the same issue I'm having, kind of unfortunate to see it just *does not* work in html/css without additional scripts, but I guess I'll have to figure something else out. Thank you for the link!